# Unable to start Apache server

Tags: apache-http-server, kali-linux

I'm new to Linux and trying to learn about it with Kali, which I have installed on an Asus Chromebook (dual boot).

Lately I've been working on installing the Apache server. I followed some forums and blogs and got the installation done. However when I tried to start the service it failed. I'm not getting enough information on what the problem is from the logs.

**Error:**

```
(kali-rolling)root@localhost:/etc/apache2# service apache2 start
[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2Invoking 'systemctl
start apache2'. Use 'systemctl status apache2' for more info. 
Running in chroot, ignoring request: start  failed! 
[warn] The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems ... (warning)
```

I tried with `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` and faced the same error as above.

I searched several forums and blogs for similar errors but most of the issues  I found had something in the error log to debug. In my case, the error log is completely empty.

I've verified the log files (`error.log` and `access.log`) under `/var/log/apache2` and they are literally empty. It looks like there was no attempt to start logging and it just failed to start.

It would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction so I can find out what I'm missing and fix the issue

Comment: [Are you sure you want to do this in Kali](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399627/108618)?

Comment: I am following a blog that had steps to install it using backtrack but i could not find any helpful links explaining installing backtrack in Chromebook. It was also mentioned that Kali and backtrack are same and is much latest. So i went for kali. I believe it should be possible to install apache on Kali... right ? any reason i should not be using it ?

Comment: "New to Linux"  == don't use Kali.

Comment: The reason is in the link I gave you.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks for the information ! i did not realize the link above earlier and just read through... seems like i should stay away and go for ubuntu or mint. Will start on it right away and thanks a lot for taking the time to point me in the right direction

Comment: @robinCTS thank you for the response... did not realize kali is not a regular OS

Comment: It is a specialist Linux distribution designed for penetration testing/hacking. It is for advanced users, with a "non-standard" setup, and is definitely *not* suitable for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

For Kali Linux:

```bsh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade

sudo service apache2 start
if error show 
sudo apt-get reinstall apache2
```